# Displaying DIV container when hovering over another

Tags: html, css

I'm having problems getting a hidden div container to display properly after hovering over a visible div container.

what happens is when d1 is hovered over d2 will appear but some kind of blinking appears. Here is what I have:

Note: I still want d1 to be visible as I would like to use d2 for displaying text over d1

http://jsfiddle.net/3ey778vc/

**css:**

```
.website{
    width:400px; height:400px; background: black;
}

.website .d1, .website .d2{
    width:100%; height:100%; float:left; 
}

.d1{
    background:red;
    width:100%; height:100%; float:left
}

.d2{
    background:blue;
    margin-top:-400px; display:none;                z-index:100;
}

.d1:hover + .d2 {
    display: block;
}
```

**html:**

```
<div class='website'>
    <div class='d1'></div>
    <div class='d2'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why not onmouseout and onmousein ?

Comment: As in JS events? Tad overkill for this particular task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.website {
    width:400px; height:400px; background: black;position:relative;
}                   
.website .d1, .website .d2 {
    left:0px;top:0px;width:100%; height:100%;
}
.d1 {
    background:red;
    width:100%; height:100%; z-index:0;position:relative;
}
.d2 {
    background:blue;
    display:none;               
    z-index:100;
    opacity:.5;
   position:absolute;
}

.website:hover .d2 {
    display: block;
}
```

This will allow you to lay one over the other. You should see a funky blue due to the opacity I added to show the effect.

Comment: I should have been more clear, I don't want to hide d1

Comment: Let me know if this answers your question.

Comment: Ok, I tried a few of your old attempts but finally you've come through. thanks

Comment: Sorry about that. Made some quick modifications before checking them against your fiddle and realized wtf did I just send, it doesn't even work.